# Can't add IBAction of a Button in my Second Storyboard

Tags: ios

I have 2 storyboard, the first storyboard has a button which when clicked will proceed to storyboard2. I have made a successful connection by creating a segue by control + drag to my second storyboard and choosing modal.

Then in my second storyboard I have a button that when clicked should randomize number. But I cannot create an IBAction (Ctrl + drag) to my ViewController.h.

Please help. I am new in IOS

Comment: In second storyboard, be sure that there is a map between this storyBoard with your view controller. (in Identity Inspector tab)

Comment: You have 2 storyboards or 2 viewControllers in the same storyboard?

Comment: Check if the targets for each story board are set correctly in the Identity Inspector tab like @nmh has said above.

Comment: thank you too @rbk for the reminder